# Correct way to bring window to foreground

Tags: powershell

I have the code below which is "supposed" to bring an application (in this case, VMware View) to the foreground/activate it.

However, this only seems to work if the window is minimized.  If it is maximized or if any other window is already activated while it is maximized, it does not seem to do anything at all.

```
# Restore VMware View window
$sig = '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);'
Add-Type -MemberDefinition $sig -Name NativeMethods -Namespace Win32
Get-Process -Name vmware-view
$hwnd = @(Get-Process vmware-view)[0].MainWindowHandle
[Win32.NativeMethods]::ShowWindowAsync($hwnd, 4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing 4 as the second parameter to `ShowWindowAsync`, its documents point to the `ShowWindows` function for a definition of the second parameter. This defines 4 (`SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE`) as:

> Displays a window in its most recent size and position. This value is similar to SW_SHOWNORMAL, except that the window is not activated.

Note the last clause.

I think you want to be using [`SetForegroundWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked:

```
Add-Type @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class SFW {
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
 [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
 public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
}
"@

$fw =  (get-process vmware-view).MainWindowHandle
[SFW]::SetForegroundWindow($fw)
```

Answer (score 2):

The definition of a *nCmdShow* of 4 (`SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE`) is:

> Displays a window in its most recent size and position. This value is
> similar to SW_SHOWNORMAL, except that the window is not activated.

And AFAIK all other *nCmdShow* types don't put any Window on top.

I would used `SetWindowPos` instead:

```
$User32 = Add-Type -Debug:$False -MemberDefinition '
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X,int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);
' -Name "User32Functions" -namespace User32Functions -PassThru

[Void]$User32::SetWindowPos($hwnd, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x53)
```

Comment: This seems the only answer that works on windows that are in the background, but not minimized. As a caveat, it keeps the window in front when not minimized instead of bringing it to front just once.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing the code found in [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/bng1ec/comment/en6a3pi/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button), I was able to bring a window to the foreground both when the window is minimized and when the window is not minimized, but in the background.

Define the following function first.

```
function SetWindowState {
param (
    [Parameter()]
    [ValidateSet('FORCEMINIMIZE', 'HIDE', 'MAXIMIZE', 'MINIMIZE', 'RESTORE', 'SHOW', 'SHOWDEFAULT', 'SHOWMAXIMIZED', 'SHOWMINIMIZED', 'SHOWMINNOACTIVE', 'SHOWNA', 'SHOWNOACTIVATE', 'SHOWNORMAL')]
    $Style = 'SHOW',
    
    [Parameter()]
    $MainWindowHandle = (Get-Process -Id $PID).MainWindowHandle
)

$WindowStates = @{
    HIDE = 0
    SHOWNORMAL = 1
    SHOWMINIMIZED = 2
    SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3
    MAXIMIZE = 3
    SHOWNOACTIVATE = 4
    SHOW = 5
    MINIMIZE = 6
    SHOWMINNOACTIVE = 7
    SHOWNA = 8
    RESTORE = 9
    SHOWDEFAULT = 10
    FORCEMINIMIZE = 11
}

$Win32ShowWindowAsync = Add-Type -Name "Win32ShowWindowAsync" -Namespace Win32Functions -PassThru -MemberDefinition @"
[DllImport("user32.dll")] 
public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
"@

$Win32ShowWindowAsync::ShowWindowAsync($MainWindowHandle, $WindowStates[$Style]) | Out-Null
}
```

Then call the function twice, in this example we bring the current Powershell window to the front. Since `RESTORE` only seems to work when the window is minimized, we simply `MINIMIZE` the window first to ensure `RESTORE` works always.

```
SetWindowState -Style MINIMIZE
SetWindowState -Style RESTORE
```