# Return Powershell ISE to the main window

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I have written a script that starts by calling Firefox several times, then calls "a read-host". My problem is that I would like ISE or the console to come back in front of the other open windows and I don't see what object or property to use.

I thank in advance all those who will help me.

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51986316/4066646

Comment: Un(fortunately) you can't force your process to the foreground, when another process has the input focus, unless that other process [enables you to set the foreground window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-allowsetforegroundwindow#remarks). With `SetForegroundWindow` and the like you are just flashing the taskbar button.